# "TypeError: _vm.$refs.dialog.save is not a function" in VuetifyJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using VueJS with VuetifyJS and I get this error as soon as I try to save the time by clicking the OK button:

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: _vm.$refs.dialog.save is not a function"

I didn't change the code - just used the [original code from the VuetifyJS example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers#example-time-dialog-and-menu):

```
 <v-flex xs11 sm5>
  <v-dialog
    ref="dialog"
    v-model="modal2"
    :return-value.sync="time"
    persistent
    lazy
    full-width
    width="290px"
  >
    <v-text-field
      slot="activator"
      v-model="time"
      label="Picker in dialog"
      prepend-icon="access_time"
      readonly
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-time-picker v-model="time" actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal2 = false">Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(time)">OK</v-btn>
    </v-time-picker>
  </v-dialog>
</v-flex>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        time: null,
        menu2: false,
        modal2: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Also as soon as the picker appears the website behind it is not visible anymore -  there should just be a black overlay on it.

I tried to update NodeJS and all dependencies to the latest version but it didn't help.
Where does this error come from? Any ideas welcome.

**UPDATE: I put the same unchanged code from the Vuetify example in `App.vue` and it worked but it still doesn't in `HelloWorld.vue` - any ideas?**

Comment: Where is the `save` method defined?

Comment: @Sphinx Can you please explain why a different v-model name should fix the issue? I tried it but got this error `[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: this.$refs.dialog.save is not a function"`

Comment: What's your `vuetify` version?

Comment: @Traxo  1.0.17: `  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.17"
  },`

Answer (score 15):

@Tom, i am not sure still you face this issue.

In case the dialog is inside "v-for", you need to follow bellow approach.

From Vue docs:

When ref is used together with v-for, the ref you get will be an array containing the child components mirroring the data source.

You need to use @click="$refs.dialog[index - 1].save(time)" instead.

Comment: This almost fixed my issue!  I was having issues with the ref inside a v-for.  I would recommend amending it to:@click="$refs.dialog[index].save(time)"

Answer (score 4):

I have this kind of error also, I did console.log the this.$ref.dialog and I found out it was an array, so I revise my code into this.$refs.dialog[0].save().

```
methods: {
    save(time) {
      this.$refs.dialog[0].save(time)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements):

> $refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and
> they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct
> child manipulation - you should avoid accessing $refs from within
> templates or computed properties.

So what you need to do is create a method handler instead.

```
<v-btn flat color="primary" @click="save(time)">OK</v-btn>
```

And in your javascript the save function call using the child reference with `ref` property, something like this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      time: null,
      menu2: false,
      modal2: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    save(time) {
      this.$refs.dialog.save(time)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. `[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: this.$refs.dialog.save is not a function"` Any ideas?

Comment: Add the function call inside a $.nextTick(function () {this.$refs.dialog.save (time)}) because it seems that for some reason the reference is not created when you try to access it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I copied from vutify. I copied the element twice so the two elements had the same ref where  I tried to fire the save function from both refs => conflict => so please check the refs if you have my problem.

for example:
if you have the first => ref="dialog" then make the second => ref="dialog2"

Answer (score 0):

If you copied from vuetify you most probably have this line in there as well:
:return-value.sync="execution_date"
For me it worked to remove this line (together with the change dialog[0])